# how to add azure subscription sqlfilter using AzureRm Powershell cmdlet?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, servicebus, azure-rm

Want to create sqlfilter under existing / new subscription.
I am able to create subscription using `New-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription` cmdlet.
But now how to delete existing filter and create new sql filter using `AzureRm`cmdlet.
I know we can use ARM template but is this not possible using AzureRm cmdlet?
Referred : [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/set-azurermservicebussubscription?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Answer (score 0):

found azure powershell cmdlet for the rule.
I will explore this now. thanks guys.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/set-azurermservicebusrule?view=azurermps-6.13.0